# controller variable in angularjs not visible on the browser

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner to angularjs and I am making a small quiz application with it. My angularjs code is:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```

```
app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.ques="";
  $scope.data={
    fd: true,
    sd: false
  };
  $scope.show=true;
  $scope.quiznum=function(quizno){
    $scope.quiz=quizno;
    $scope.myfunc();
  }
  $scope.myfunc=function(){
      var url="http://localhost:3000/quizzes/";
      console.log($scope.count);
      $http.post(url,{'quizno':$scope.quiz,'question':++$scope.count})
      .then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.status=="ongoing"){
           $scope.data={
               fd: false,
               sd: true
           };
           $scope.ques = response.data.ques;
           console.log($scope.ques);
           $scope.show=true;
        }
        else{
           $scope.data={
               fd: false,
               sd: true
           };
           $scope.ques = response.data.status;
           $scope.show=false;
        }
      });
  }
}]);
```

```
app.directive("secondDirective", function() {
    return {
        templateUrl : "maincontent.html",
        controller: "myctrl"
    };
});
```

The maincontent.html file is:

```html
<div ng-controller="myctrl" style="position: relative;top: 10px;left: 40%;">
<h3>{{ques}}</h3><br></br>
    <button ng-click="myfunc()" ng-show="show">Next question</button>
</div>
```

first file which will show up is:

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
<first-directive ng-show="data.fd"></first-directive>
<second-directive ng-show="data.sd" ng-init="quiz=0;count=0"></second-directive>
</div>
</body>
```

As the user clicks on any one of the link of the quiz provided, he/she is taken to the question one of that quiz. But the problem is that although I get first question as response from the server, it is not visible on the page i.e. h3 tag in the maincontent file remains empty. But this problem happens only to the first question of any quiz. Afterwards, all questions are visible. I have tried every possible thing I know, but it is not working.
Please help!!

Comment: I am not sure how it is working for 2nd question onwards. Because as per the below code, once you are receiving the response and setting to "ques", you are setting the show to false. Even you will have ques, you are not showing to UI. Please confirm.
--
           $scope.ques = response.data.status;
           $scope.show=false;

Comment: I've edited the code and have made each question to be printed on the console with the line "console.log($scope.ques)". All questions are visible on the console,including the first one but only the first question is not visible on the UI.

Comment: So, myfunc is being called either from quiznum function call or when user press on button. Can you please tell, when the page loads then are you calling quiznum function to get the response? If so, then when you are calling quiznum function ?

Comment: Let me tell you the complete scenarion: At the very basic, i have two directives on the main page. When the page loads, first directive shows up in which there are links to all quizzes. When user clicks  on any one of them, quiznum function is called with quiz number as the arguement. As soon as a link is clicked, first directive becomes hidden and second one shows up. So quiznum function is called only one time.Afterwards, myfunc gets called for each button click.

Comment: Don't know why ques is being printed on console but not on the UI

Answer (score 0):

question is in ++$scope.count instead $scope.count in myfunc() .

```
$scope.data={
               fd: false,
               sd: true
           };
```

above scope using in if and else case  without changing ...so if needed make it out of the loop.

```
$scope.ques = response.data.status;
           $scope.show=false;
```

ng-show seems false and notshowing in UI why need to upadate $scope.ques..use ng-if instead ng-show.

Comment: Answer is  provided in first line.. There is no clarification there ... as he is the beginner , it will help.

Comment: But I still don't understand why the question is printed on the console but not on the UI. I have also removed ng-show

Comment: where the $scope.count is declared and why needed in question???? the cause is not with ng-show ....i suggested ng-if  ....but look at the problem ...actually what you need?...while selecting the respective question your question get to show to user??? (ie) while clicking the question  quiznum(quizno)is called?where you get the quizno ? by values in ng-repeat?....your code contains little beginner mistake man ...

Comment: I'll show you my complete code once I open my system